# file size seems bigger than normal in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, parquet, orc

I'm using the maprR Sandbox to test different setups in hive and MaprFs.
I got basically two stages on MaprFs. The first stage consists of a folder that stores a single Table in AvroContainer-Format. The avro header contains only a link to the external stored .avsc file (avro scheme). These avro files had been created by flume. From there one I created an external Table in hive, based on those avro files.

Then, I created a parquet and an orc table as a second stage with the same scheme the following way:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE prc_cpn_orc 
LIKE stg_cpn
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 'hdfs:////environments/icm/data/prc/public/cpn/orc'
TBLPROPERTIES ( "orc.compress"="snappy" );

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE prc_cpn_prq 
LIKE stg_cpn
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'hdfs:////environments/icm/data/prc/public/cpn/prq'
TBLPROPERTIES ( "parquet.compress"="snappy" );
```

After the tables had been created, I inserted the data from the avro table:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE prc_cpn_orc
SELECT * FROM stg_cpn;

INSERT INTO TABLE prc_cpn_prq
SELECT * FROM stg_cpn;
```

Now comes the confusing part, the avro table is way smaller than the other two tables. After all I did read, avro should have the worst compression. All three file formats using the snappy compression codec here.

This is how the resulting Table scheme looks like for all three:

```
1   cpn_id  int 
2   cmpgn_id    int 
3   cstmr_id    int 
4   cpn_barcode int 
5   cpn_text    string  
6   cpn_address string  
7   cpn_phone   string  
8   cpn_timezone    string  
9   cpn_partner string  
10  cpn_created_at  string
```

Every table contains 16 million rows.

**Results:**

- JSON Input Folder Size: 3.42GB (Input for Flume)
- Avro Table: 791.75MB (700 files generated by Flume SerDe)
- ORC Table: 1.17GB (6 files generated by Hive SerDe)
- Parquet Table: 1.84GB (6 files generated by Hive SerDe)

**In theory, ORC should consume ~ 2 times less space than avro, so how can it be the opposite in my case? Did I miss something?**

Comment: how did you get the table size?

Comment: I'm using the hue Data Browser that shows me the characteristics of each Hive Table

Comment: try `show tblproperties your_table` and check the size

Comment: it's roughly the same result